# Sentinel-1 image decible in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I've wrote this code for Sentinel-1 decible image. although it doesn't show any error but decible image contains many NaN values.

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0803e3f7e3518013e310f7d1c666acf9

```
var fall = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2018-10-01','2019-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.equals('instrumentMode','IW'))
.select('VV')
.median()
.clip(table)
.focal_median(50,'square','meters')
.log10().multiply(10.0)
.rename('fall');

Map.addLayer(fall);
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: although it doesn't show any error but image result, is not correct. the most of the pixels have nan values!

Comment: please edit the question to update it with new information

Comment: ok, I did it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for [remember](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/ln/Ln_of_Negative_Number.html):

> What is the natural logarithm of a negative number?
>   The natural logarithm function ln(x) is defined only for x>0.
>   So the natural logarithm of a negative number is undefined.

Sentinel-1 product has mainly negative values (range -50 to 1), removing `.log10()`:

[image]

Also, check **Sentinel-1 SAR GRD** product description:

> Each scene was pre-processed with Sentinel-1 Toolbox using the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Thermal noise removal
> 2. Radiometric calibration
> 3. Terrain correction using SRTM 30 or ASTER DEM for areas greater than
>      60 degrees latitude, where SRTM is not available. **The final
>      terrain corrected values are converted to decibels via log scaling
>      (10*log10(x).**

You are trying to pre-process data already pre-processed